# Print an x509 certificate c++

Tags: c++, openssl, x509certificate

I have an x509 certificate pointer like
`x509* cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(connection);`

What is the function that I should use to print the complete certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X509_NAME_print_ex family of functions is your [answer](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/X509_NAME_print_ex.html).

Comment: It takes `X509_NAME` as an argument. Not X509.

Answer (score 1):

X509_print and X509_print_fp is a simpler choice if you want to print all certificate data.
[Link to docs](http://fossies.org/dox/openssl-1.0.1c/t__x509_8c.html#a3334cd2019f6197e4a2be131fd6932ff)

Answer (score 1):

This will print the certificate to console

> PEM_write_X509(stdout, peer);